# Using TEXTJOIN adding "and" between

Tags: excel-formula

using=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,D2, "and",I2) this works were there is a value in I, How do I eliminate the "and" when there is not a value in I?

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,D2, IF(I2<>"","and,"& I2,""))`
```

Comment: when using the above formula it returns the following results;

Comment: Vincent,and, Laura

Comment: How do i remove the commas after each name?

Comment: just do `=TEXTJOIN(" and ",True,D2,I2)`